# Applying CSS Styles to an existing table that is constructed as a tree

Tags: html, css, firefox

Is it possible to apply a CSS style to an existing HTML table that is constructed as a tree?

For example, in Firefox, the Bookmarks Library table is constructed as a tree.  Is it possible to apply a CSS style to one of the columns (but not the others)?

Using `treechildren` it is trivial to apply a style to an entire row.  But how about applying a style to just one column?

Comment: How does your code look like? Please post a demo of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `treechildren:-moz-tree-cell-text(*property*)`, replacing *property* with the appropriate property name.

For example:

```
#placeContent > treechildren:-moz-tree-cell-text(placesContentTags) {
   color: blue !important;
}
```

Will color the tags column blue.

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

CSS nth child should help you solve your problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child

Here's a quick example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0gztemg6/

And the CSS from the above example:

```
td:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but each column has a class, so I'm not sure how the nth-child pseudo-class will help.  Can you provide more detail?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I've added an example.

Comment: Thanks Ian, unfortunately, that's a table constructed as a table, not as a tree.  But that's okay, I appreciate your help anyways.  I figured it out and will post the answer in a moment.